# How can I reconnect a USB device (NOT A STORAGE DEVICE) without physically unplugging?

Tags: usb, parallels-desktop

So I'm using Windows on Parallels Desktop for some application. After I disconnect the USB device from the virtual machine, it is not automatically connected back to macOS. I can still see the device on System Report>USB but I cannot use it for anything. Device needs to be kept plugged in for power so I can't unplug and plug back in.

Is there any way to reconnect it?

All I found so far was using diskutil but it works only with storage devices so it doesn't help my problem.

Comment: Is there a switch in parallel desktop that switches the usb device back and forth to and out of the vm ?

Comment: @FrontENG (On Parallels Desktop 11) There is a dropdown menu for devices in which I can click on a device to disconnect from vm, but when I do that the device disappears from the menu and I still can't use it on mac. 
I tried Parallels Desktop 14 on my other mac today and I can successfully switch back and forth on that from the said menu. Still curious if there is any way to do what I ask though.

Comment: Can you see your usb device in diskutility?

Comment: @FrontENG Nope, It's not a storage device just an evaluation board

Comment: Try “sudo launchctl stop usbd && sudo launchctl start usbd” in terminal

Comment: It didn't work. Guess I'll just switch to Parallels 14.